# How can I deserialize a nested wrapped String in Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2, mongo-jackson-mapper

I have a JSON string that contains a nested and wrapped JSON string. I'd like to deserialize this  using Jackson but I'm unsure how. Here's a sample bean:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SomePerson {

    public final String ssn;
    public final String birthday;
    public final Address address;

    @JsonCreator
    public SomePerson(
            @JsonProperty("ssn") String ssn,
            @JsonProperty("birthday") String birthday,
            @JsonProperty("data") Address address,
            @JsonProperty("related") List<String> related) {
        this.ssn = ssn;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.address = address;
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class Address {

        public final String city;
        public final String country;

        @JsonCreator
        public Address(
                @JsonProperty("city") String city,
                @JsonProperty("country") String country) {
            this.city = city;
            this.country = country;
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON string resembles this:

```
{
  ssn: "001",
  birthday: "01.01.2020",
  address: "{ city: \"London\", country: \"UK\" }"
}
```

While I've deserialized nsted objects before - I'm rather lost as to how to do this when the object is a wrapped string.

Comment: Why is "address" a String in your model? It should be an instance of the Address type.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It was a typo. 

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Take a look also at: [Is it possible to make Jackson serialize a nested object as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141480/is-it-possible-to-make-jackson-serialize-a-nested-object-as-a-string?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When internal object is escaped `JSON String` we need to deserialise it "twice". First time is run when root `JSON Object` is deserialised and second time we need to run manually. To do that we need to implement custom deserialiser which implements `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ContextualDeserializer` interface. It could look like this:

```
class FromStringJsonDeserializer<T> extends StdDeserializer<T> implements ContextualDeserializer {

    /**
     * Required by library to instantiate base instance
     * */
    public FromStringJsonDeserializer() {
        super(Object.class);
    }

    public FromStringJsonDeserializer(JavaType type) {
        super(type);
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String value = p.getValueAsString();

        return ((ObjectMapper) p.getCodec()).readValue(value, _valueType);
    }


    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property) {
        return new FromStringJsonDeserializer<>(property.getType());
    }
}
```

We need to annotate our property with this class:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = FromStringJsonDeserializer.class)
public final Address address;
```

Since now, you should be able to deserialise above `JSON` payload to your `POJO` model.

See also:

- [How to inject dependency into Jackson Custom deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54777586/how-to-inject-dependency-into-jackson-custom-deserializer)
- [Is it possible to configure Jackson custom deserializers at class level for different data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55462381/is-it-possible-to-configure-jackson-custom-deserializers-at-class-level-for-diff)

Comment: Very detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

[`readValue(String,Class)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)) should work:

```
Address addObject = mapper.readValue(root.getString("address"), Address.class);
```

Where `root` is your main **`JSONObject`**.