# How to deserialize raw JSON to Java object with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've got two POJOs:

```java
@lombok.Value
public class Foo {
  String foo;
  Bar bar;
}

@lombok.Value
public class Bar {
  String bar;
  String baz;
}
```

I'd like to be able to deserialize the following to a `Foo` instance:

```json
{
  "foo": "some foo",
  "bar": "{ \"bar\": \"some bar\", \"baz\": \"some baz\" }"
}
```

If I understand it correctly this the exact opposite `@JsonRawValue`. There, it convert a Java String value (which is valid JSON value) to JSON object. But here, I need to convert a JSON string value to Java object.
I suspect that I need to write a custom deserializer, but I'm not sure how exactly since it involves parsing the raw JSON and assign it to the field. Maybe `BeanDeserializerModifier`? (I have no idea how to use it.)
I'd like to keep the object immutable (`@Value`), but I can drop this requirement if it helps solving the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to make Jackson serialize a nested object as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51141480/5221149)

Comment: Take a look on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66188646/51591). If you have `JSON` payload put as `String` into another `JSON` payload you need to deserialise it two times. First at root level, and next on escaped level.

Comment: Both questions are relevant, checking them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66188646/51591) question mentioned by @Michał Ziober I managed to do it. Posting it here for reference since it was kinda tricky to get it working (with `@Value` and `CamelCase` property naming in JSON):

```json
{
  "Foo": "some foo",
  "Bar": "{ \"bar\": \"some bar\", \"baz\": \"some baz\" }"
}
```

And the implementation is:

```java
@Value
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Foo.FooBuilder.class)
public class Foo {
    @JsonAlias("Foo") // note this!
    String foo;
    Bar bar;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class FooBuilder {
        @JsonAlias("Bar") // note this!
        @JsonDeserialize(using = BarDeserializer.class)
        public FooBuilder bar(Bar bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
            return this;
        }
    }
}

@lombok.Value
public class Bar {
  String bar;
  String baz;
}

public class BarDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Bar> {
    public BarDeserializer() {
        super(Bar.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Bar deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
        return (Bar) ((ObjectMapper) p.getCodec()).readValue(p.getValueAsString(), _valueClass);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use FooDto class delete this  `Bar bar;` from DtoClass

or use this

```
@lombok.Value
public class Foo {
  String foo;
  @JsonIgnore
  Bar bar;
}
```

Comment: delete the field? why? I need the field.

Comment: delete field from Dto class like this `public class FooDot' 
not Entity class 

`public class Foo'

Comment: but in your case use @JsonIgnore annotation